# Json output for android

Tags: php, android

i am using this [tutorial](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)

please guide me how can i customized it for my mysql table which is like this 
[image]

i am unable to understand how to get this sort of out from my table .

```
 {"earthquakes": [
        {
            "eqid": "c0001xgp",
            "magnitude": 8.8,
            "lng": 142.369,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
            "depth": 24.4,
            "lat": 38.322
      },
      {
            "eqid": "2007hear",
            "magnitude": 8.4,
            "lng": 101.3815,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2007-09-12 09:10:26",
            "depth": 30,
            "lat": -4.5172
      }
    <--more -->
    ]}
```

i am using php . Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear, what do you want to do, exactly? Getting the data from your database and giving a JSON format?

Comment: i have tried it with this  while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

              $res[]=$arr;

           print(json_encode($res));

Comment: @Cristian yes like stated in the tutorial

Comment: What you're doing looks fine, it should create an array of objects similar to the example. But it wont follow the exact same structure. In the example its an object with a field "earthquakes" which is an array of objects. In your code, it'll be just an array of objects.

Comment: thanks Cristian its done . i have adopted this while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
 $arr[] = $obj;
}
 
echo '{"sample":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

Comment: Another solution could have been: $jobj[sample]=$arr; json_encode($jobj); which should lead to the same result

Comment: I meant $jobj[sample]=$arr; echo json_encode($jobj);

Comment: yeah it can also be one of good ways . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial shows how to consume JSON in the android client.

Try some of these tutorials for the server side part of the equation:

- ["Creating JSON Data in PHP"](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aCreating_JSON_Data_in_PHP)
- ["Using a Custom Class to create JSON
  in PHP"](http://particletree.com/notebook/using-a-custom-class-to-create-json-in-php/)
- ["Creating JSON Data in PHP"](http://www.vinylfox.com/creating-json-data-in-php/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation for json_encode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and also see if these examples help:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aCreating_JSON_Data_in_PHP

http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json